# Call to undefined method SprintListController::buildApplicationPage()

Tags: phabricator, burndowncharts

I want to install phabricator-extensions-Sprint for phabricator. I followed the installation below:

> To install the Sprint extension:
>
> update your phabricator and libphutil to HEAD run git clone
>   https://github.com/wikimedia/phabricator-extensions-Sprint.git
>   /srv/phab/libext/sprint from the /srv/phab/phabricator/bin directory
>   run:
>
> ./config set load-libraries '{"sprint":"/srv/phab/libext/sprint/src"}'

But when I ran the Sprint in Application, I received the bug:

```
>>> UNRECOVERABLE FATAL ERROR <<<

Call to undefined method SprintListController::buildApplicationPage()

/opt/phabricator/libext/sprint/src/controller/SprintListController.php:46


┻━┻ ︵ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ︵ ┻━┻
```

I have to tried to do [adding_new_classes](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/) but not effected. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sprint extension was recently broken by this commit in Phabricator:
https://secure.phabricator.com/rP2201c65eb73fb99b8625bea45c273d262f2c289f#19bb764c

The quick fix is to restore removed `buildApplicationPage` method by putting it into `src/controller/SprintListController.php`, it will fix the bug you describe.

However using Sprint extension looks like a questionable choice in the long run, given the problems discussed here:
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T90906